# custom tags not working in ie8

Tags: css, ie8-compatibility-mode

I tried making custom tags so that uses can enter text that displays something with red or bold etc when rendered as HTML for eg,

```
<rb>text here becomes red and bold</rb> and goes to default here
```

this gets rendered in a div with class 'note' and i have the following css set up

```
.note rb
{
    color:Red;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

It works in ie9, chrome, firefox but doesnt work in ie8. How can I make it work there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To please the senior browsers ( IE8 and older) I would just go with something like:

HTML:

```
<span class="RB">text here becomes red and bold</span> and goes to default here
```

CSS:

```
.RB {color:Red; font-weight:bold; }
```

This targets all the `RB` classes. So you only need to wrap everything inside

`<span class="RB">` `</span>`

Comment: I have more than 1 of those tags. so just setting the span css wont work.

Answer (score 19):

if you don't mind a little javascript:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script>
document.createElement("rb");
</script>
<![endif]-->
```

if you want to add several elements/tags, you can:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script>
// bold, italic, underlined, striked
els = ['rb', 'ri', 'ru', 'rs'];
for(i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
    document.createElement(els[i]);
    }
</script>
<![endif]-->
```

### Update

Looks like ability to define custom elements is in the work ([W3C Working Draft 6 June 2013](http://www.w3.org/TR/components-intro/#custom-element-section))

Some projects that use this:

- [Google’s Polymer](http://www.polymer-project.org/)
- [Mozilla’s X-Tags](http://www.x-tags.org/)
- [Mozilla’s Brick](http://mozilla.github.io/brick/)

### See also:

- [Introducing Brick: Minimal-markup Web Components for Faster App Development](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2013/08/introducing-brick-minimal-markup-web-components-for-faster-app-development/) (Aug 27, 2013)
- [Custom Elements: defining new elements in HTML](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/customelements/) (Aug 28, 2013)
- [Custom Elements: a web components gallery for modern web apps](http://customelements.io/)

Comment: This is the "correct" answer to the problem as stated, although I respectfully suggest that your approach itself—using custom tags for stylistic purposes—is rather ghastly. (Note that you will need to add this code somewhere in the head of your document for it to work.)

Comment: Keep in mind, this is NOT valid HTML5.  If you want your page to validate (and most developers should), then you can't create your own custom tags. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9845011/are-custom-elements-valid-html5/9848864#9848864

Comment: @JeremyMoritz a comment to that answer says that this is ( or will be ) now correct HTML5.

Comment: @tomdemuyt After hours of searching, I have not seen a credible source stating that one can make custom html elements while following current HTML5 spec.  There are plenty of assumptions from developers, but the spec appears to be consistent and clear (http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-body-element), and the w3c validator always throws errors on custom elements.  If this gets changed in the future, that's fine, but I'm fairly sure that nothing has changed yet, so developers would be advised to follow current standards

Comment: yes yes yes, using custom tags is 'ghastly'. But this is how things are rolling these days with frameworks like Angular et. al. So very useful to know for those occaisons - in fact this is basically the technique suggested in the Angular docs (http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie)

Comment: Angular is just a Javascript framework. Anyone can make one of those. For the sake of your users (especially the visually disabled ones), and for SEO, follow HTML5.