# Custom CSS Tags

Tags: c#, css, html

I am developing an chat application.  The message display is all html, so html tags work for text formatting.  I would like it if tags like `<red></red>` etc. would change the text color.  Is there anyway to define new tags like that, or will I just have to replace the fake tags with actual html?

Comment: well you can use custom css selectors red { color: rgb(255,0,0); }

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6854757/custom-tags-not-working-in-ie8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In all modern browsers you can use your own tags in a literal sense (however note that its **not** valid HTML/XHTML markup):

```
<red>some red text</red>
```

Then in CSS:

```
red { color: red; }
```

However in IE8 and below you will need to use some JavaScript to allow Internet Explorer to style 'made-up' tags (in the same way that you active the new HTML5 tags such as `article`, `section`, etc.

```
document.createElement('red');
```

Here is [a JSFiddle illustrating the above](http://jsfiddle.net/fzGWy/).

Comment: So if I define document.createElement('red') then I can use the css red { color: red; } and <red> Text </red> and it will work?

Comment: I can't get that to work in my application.  I am loading an included webPage.  I did the document thing, and declared the css stuff.  Any idea what's missing?

Comment: Ensure the that `document.createElement('red')` is in the `<head>` element of the parent (containing) HTML page.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's safer to stick to `<span class="red"></span>`. This is HTML not XML/XLST.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [LessCSS](http://lesscss.org) which is basically kind of "pre-processor" for CSS. There is also a [.NET version](http://www.dotlesscss.org/).

The preprocessor understands simple variables, built-in functions and similar helper constructs that saves you from writing repetitive code.

An example is:

```
@brand_color: #4D926F;

#header {
  color: @brand_color;
}

h2 {
  color: @brand_color;
}
```