# Are Non-HTML tags in a HTML document bad for SEO?

Tags: html, seo

Is it a bad practice have non-HTML tags of the page? I need to use them for internal content processing needs and wonder if there are any troubles with it (SEO for example)?

Comment: Do you mean like `<example>` by non-html tag?

Comment: AFAIK, normal practice is to use `<script type='text/x-your-custom-type'>whatever you want</script>`

Comment: @kingdamian42 yes. different `<snippet>`, `<test>` etc..

Comment: Take a look for an in depth explanation [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802687/is-there-a-way-to-create-your-own-html-tag-in-html5)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO, not programming.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9845011/are-custom-elements-valid-html5

Comment: @BilltheLizard, there are 4076 questions tagged SEO on Stackoverflow. does this one more off-topic than the others?

Comment: Most of those are off-topic as well, but I don't have time to go through them all today.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it is bad. Not particularly for SEO but for browsers. You are relying on the browser to ignore your tags and render the page correctly. Since every rendering engine loads a page slightly differently, you have no way of knowing how it will handle your bad html.

Can you wrap them in html comments? Like so:

```
<!--<not a real tag>-->
```

The browser and spiders will ignore these but since they are still part of the html, your parser *might* still be able to read them.

An alternative is to use [HTML5's custom data attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#custom-data-attribute). Your parser should also be able to read these.

W3C also have an experimental [custom elements spec](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/webcomponents/raw-file/tip/spec/custom/index.html). Browser support looks poor at present but this may be of interest in future.

Comment: Agree with this posts advice and +1'd it but standard practice is for a html user-agent to disregard anything it doesn't understand. This is why things like custom data attributes work and are safely ignored in older browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's bad for browsers (and a little for SEO). Each browser could interpret a random tag on its own way.

If you need to do *internal content processing*, you can store your data in attributes of your existing HTML tags, with [`data-*` attributes](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/) (HTML5 spec.), like this:

```
<div class="simple-div" data-file="./abc.txt" data-pattern="(.+)"></div>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" data-objID="42">My link!</a>
```

The HTML document shouldn't store data anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what you want to do specifically, but you could use an invisible div or hidden field with custom data attributes? or even a comment?