# Using undefined tag name in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css

For example,

```css
chapter {
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<book>
    Harry Potter
    <chapter>
        Chapter 1
    </chapter>
    <chapter>
        Chapter 2
    </chapter>    
</book>
```

This HTML snippet has clear syntax, however, I am not sure whether it  is supported by most browsers. And is there any drawbacks for this approach, such as SEO issues?

Comment: You can do whatever you want, but this is *invalid* HTML

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen but modern browser can render it well, that is where I am confused..

Comment: Possible dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17923853/are-non-html-tags-in-a-html-document-bad-for-seo or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9845011/are-custom-elements-valid-html5

Comment: @hanfeisun They can render it because the tags are *syntactically* correct (the code is properly written). The problem is that they are not *semantically* correct (the browser does not know what they *mean*).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are talking about custom HTML tags here. You can "create" custom HTML elements which is supported by most modern browsers.

internet Explorer does not recognise any of these tags unless you first 'create' them with JavaScript:

```
document.createElement('tagName');
```

**Note:** All custom elements have `display: inline` by default which can be modified by CSS or JavaScript. Custom tags are also not valid in HTML5.

Answer (score 1):

This is fine, in principle, but I would use XHTML5 instead of HTML5 as it allows for the introduction of alternative XML namespaces. Then I would use your custom elements in their own namespace to avoid collisions (in case a future HTML revision adds `book` and `chapter` elements, for example).

```
<html xmlns:hanfeisun="http://someReservedURIPossiblyYourXsdPath">
...
    <hanfesisun:book>
        <hanfesisun:chapter>
            Chapter 1
        </hanfesisun:chapter>
    </hanfesisun:book>
...
</html>
```

In CSS you need to use the `@namespace` block ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@namespace )

```
@namespace hanfeisun url(http://someReservedURIPossiblyYourXsdPath);

hanfeisun|chapter { display: block; }
```

For brevity's sake you can use a shorter namespace prefix, like just `h` instead of `hanfeisun`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use semanthic html5(article, summary etc) with a schema type which fits your content: https://schema.org/Book, so there's no need to create additional HTML tags

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about web components (custom made html elements). A standardized way of implementing this is subject of development in a working group at the W3C. In case you're interested in their progress:

http://w3c.github.io/webcomponents/spec/custom/

It is about far more than just making any custom tag display properly across browsers:

> Though it was long possible to create DOM elements with any tag names
>   in HTML, these elements weren't very functional. By giving Web
>   developers the means to both inform the parser on how to properly
>   construct an element and to react to lifecycle changes of an element,
>   the specification eliminates the need for DOM-as-a-render-view
>   scaffolding that has to exist today in most web frameworks or
>   libraries.