# Valid HTML5 tag and attribute

Tags: html

I would like to know if this code is allowed?

```
<article intro> .... </article>
```

I would like to use this if this is valid as attribute/elements of HTML5. If possible, i wanted to use this to simplify my HTML / CSS connection. Instead of using **class="intro"** will use **[intro]**.

Comment: We have [validator.w3.org/](http://validator.w3.org/)

Comment: Yes sir, however i saw one time a site that uses this kind of element. But after i check it to validator. "Attribute **intro** not allowed on element **article** at this point".

Comment: Ok thank you Mr. Alien got your point.
Btw, this custom attributes makes me confused. Let say, instead of using `class="intro"` for my CSS, I'll use `intro` to make it look like **[intro]** than to this **.intro**. But referring to my comment, it is not valid as it is for HTML5. As @nisarg statement [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17700529/852916) _"Custom tags are not valid in HTML5. But currently browsers are supporting to parse them and also you can use them using css."_
Thank You for your time.

Comment: Wait wait, what you are trying here, where did `class` came here?

Comment: Aside from the HTML, i would like also to apply it to my CSS to simplify the attributes/elements styling. Well, i guess i will stick to the legit attributes than to this.

Comment: Nah, don't do that, instead follow the default approach, the way you are doing is wrong

Comment: Yes I will not do that.  Thank you for your time, I appreciate it.  :)

Answer (score 1):

Use following  validating tool for HTML 5 :

http://html5.validator.nu/

http://validator.w3.org/

Use this code :

```
<article data-intro> .... </article>
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Then what is the answer for checking the validate HTML?

Comment: Here he can check "HTML is valid or not".

Comment: Here he can get answer with suggestion and even also with solution. I think its better way to check validate HTML.

Comment: See the above comment i.e :" Yes sir, however i saw one time a site that uses this kind of element. But after i check it to validator. "Attribute intro not allowed on element article at this point". – user852916"