# custom elements vs web-components custom elements

Tags: javascript, html, web-component, w3c

I just started with custom elements and according to [this](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/customelements/) article, a custom element can be defined as follows:

```
var proto = Object.create(HTMLElement.prototype);
proto.createdCallback = function () { ... };
proto.enteredViewCallback = function () { ... };
document.register('x-foo', {
    prototype: proto
});
```

This works great in my chrome browser, every time I create a new element the 'createdCallback' is called.

Now, if I look at the official documentation [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/components-intro/#custom-element-section) I don't see, for example, the createdCallback mentioned anywhere. Does someone understand the W3C documentation and can explain why this is ?

Furthermore, looking at [custom elements from web-components](http://www.w3.org/TR/components-intro/#custom-element-section) they look completely different. So now there are two different types of custom elements. This doesn't make any sense or is there a good reason these two can exist together ?

Comment: After reading [are-custom-elements-valid-html5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9845011/) i am almost sure that my assumptions are correct. But to be sure: Is the name of the custom element `x-foo`? Would you use it like this `<x-foo>my foo custom element</x-foo>`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `createdCallback` was previously called `readyCallback`:

> Custom elements have lifecycle callbacks which can be used to set up
>   presentational aspects of a custom element. These are: readyCallback,
>   which is called after a custom element is created; insertedCallback,
>   which is called after a custom element is inserted into a document;
>   and removedCallback, which is called after a custom element is removed
>   from a document

http://www.w3.org/TR/components-intro/#lifecycle-callbacks

This was changed in the following Bug entry: [Bug 22564 - [Custom]: Rename readyCallback to createdCallback](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/webcomponents/rev/a0559f51ecb7). Discussion [here](https://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/show_bug.cgi?id=22564).

The reason it isn't in the spec was because the bug was resolved in July 2013 and the draft updated in June. Such are the pitfalls of following working drafts!