# jQuery is unable to select cells outside table

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I know using `<td>` outside `<table>` is an invalid markup but it is still a node in HTML DOM. That is why I am able to see those two cells rendered. `jQuery` is unable to get me those cells. Here is the [JSBin Demo](http://jsbin.com/wimixuxi/2/edit?html,css,output) and Code

## HTML

```
<table>
  <tr><td class='cell1'>Cell inside table</td></tr>
</table>

<tr>
  <td class='cell2'>Cells without table</td>
  <td class='cell2'>Cells without table</td>
</tr>
```

## JS

```
var $a = $('#a');

var numCells1 = $('.cell1').length;
var numCells2 = $('.cell2').length;

$a.html('Num Cell1:' + numCells1 + '  Num Cell2:' + numCells2);
```

## Output

```
Num Cell1:1 Num Cell2:0
```

Why Num Cell2 is 0? What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Changing your second query to `$('td').length` results in `1`...so I guess invalid markup is disregarded.  Interesting.

Comment: Note that you CAN create partials (DOM element hierarchy not in the document) in jQuery, and insert them into the document later. As was stated below, you just can't drop improper elements into the document itself.

Comment: @JimCote I understand but my doubt is Why browser removed the `<td>` tag but not the `<imaginary>` tag in this case http://jsbin.com/wimixuxi/2/edit?html,css,js,output

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is the browser doing its trick, nothing wrong with jQuery. The browser won't render the `<tr>` if its not within a `table` and will just strip off all the tags leaving out just plain text. Check your elements panel in browser to see the markup.. there is no element with a class of `cell2`

Answer (score 4):

Inspect the element, you'll see that the browser threw away the invalid markup and is just displaying the text.

[image]

Comment: Isn't it strange that it threw away `<tr>` tag as well. Browser does not throw away invalid HTML tags. See this http://jsbin.com/wimixuxi/2/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: @blunderboy well, it does throw away. At least it did in the jsBin you provided in the comment.

Comment: @blunderboy that is a custom tag and not invalid markup check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802687/is-there-a-way-to-create-your-own-html-tag-in-html5 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9845011/are-custom-elements-valid-html5

Comment: I find it stranger that it keeps your <imaginary> tag than that it throws away the invalid <tr> and <td>s.

Answer (score 1):

> but it is still a node in HTML DOM

That's a wrong assumption, see [3.2.1 Semantics](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/CR-html5-20140204/dom.html#semantics-0):

> Authors must not use elements, attributes, or attribute values for purposes other than their appropriate intended semantic purpose, as doing so prevents software from correctly processing the page.
>
> [...]
>
> Authors must not use elements, attributes, or attribute values that are not permitted by this specification or other applicable specifications, as doing so makes it significantly harder for the language to be extended in the future.

Especially since the HTML5 recommendation dictates a specific parser behaviour, where `<tr>` gets only parsed correctly in the "in table" state.

See also:

- [Unexpected markup in tables](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#unexpected-markup-in-tables) (related, shows other quirks with tables)

Answer (score 1):

TR is only valid inside a TABLE. The browser is probably ignoring completely that part of the HTML.

You can always use the SCRIPT tag to put whatever you want inside

```
<script id="something" type="text/template"><tr><td>whatever</td></tr></script>
```

and use jQuery to recreate the element:

```
var tr = $( $('#something').html() );
```