# html5 doesn't support accordion tag

Tags: html, angularjs, accordion, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to use the accordion tag from angularjs bootstrap, however, in the IDE it says that `Validation (HTML5): Element accordion is not supported`. I've been searching around for the issue, but it seems like not many people encounter this issue.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9845011/are-custom-elements-valid-html5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the accordion tag is not HTML5 its a custom element thus your IDE is not going to validate it.

[more info on custom elements/tags](http://w3c.github.io/webcomponents/spec/custom/)

Comment: But wouldn't the tag still work even though it doesn't pass the validation which is just an IDE thing?

Comment: yes it will work. Its just an IDE thing!

Comment: It doesn't seem to be recognized by the browser.