# Div is not toggling on click

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have two div's, the one that I will be clicking is "InterestsHeader". The one that I want to toggle is "Interests"

This code doesn't seem to work, I'm sure that it is to do with my div - InterestsHeader but can't spot anything.

```js
$(".InterestsHeader").click(function() {
  $(".Interests").toggle("fast");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="InterestsHeader">
  <headerdivtext>&#9660; Personal Information</headerdivtext>
</div>

<div class="Interests">
  <b>Test header</b>
  <br />
  <p>
    test div stuff
  </p>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        test
      </td>
      <td>
        test
      </td>
      <td>
        test
      </td>
      <td>
        test
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        test
      </td>
      <td>
        test
      </td>
      <td>
        test
      </td>
      <td>
        test
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: you don't have any element with the Interests class

Comment: Sorry I forgot to put this into the initial question. Could you take another look now please?

Comment: it works fine http://codepen.io/jcastillo/pen/aOyrQg  look at your browser console to see if there's any error and make sure you have the jquery library

Comment: Works fine here too as soon as I add jQuery to your code - try running your snippet

Comment: Perhaps you need to cater for old IEs? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9845011/are-custom-elements-valid-html5

Comment: Yep the code works fine in codepen. I'm getting no errors on my browser console. I've get the jquery library needed. This one is really stumping me. I'll try looking at different broswers.

Comment: Seems to work OK in your fiddle.

Answer (score 2):

You dont have any element in your html with class `.Interests`.

HTML:

```
<div class="InterestsHeader">
    <headerdivtext>&#9660; Personal Information</headerdivtext>
</div>
<div class="Interests"></div>
```

JQUERY:

```
$(".InterestsHeader").click(function () {
    $(".Interests").toggle("fast");
});
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to put this into the initial question. Could you take another look now please?