# How to add custom html tag in CKEditor?

Tags: drupal, ckeditor, drupal-8

I want to add a custom tag like this:

```
<myTag>text</myTag>
```

How do I apply HTML properties to a custom tag?

Comment: Related: [Are custom elements valid HTML5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9845011/are-custom-elements-valid-html5)

Comment: Not recommended but can do using "Source" option.

Answer (score 1):

- Navigate to `/admin/config/content/formats/manage/full_html`
- Tick on "Limit allowed HTML tags and correct faulty HTML".
  You will get an option to put your custom tag with allowed attributes.

[image: Limit allowed HTML tags and correct faulty HTML]

- Add your new tag(s) separated by space, eg: `<mytag attribute-1 attribute-2>`

Hope this helps.