# Proper way to apply CSS to HTML5 custom elements

Tags: css, html

I have a custom HTML5 tag called `<scroll-content>`. This tag actually gets created and inserted for me by a framework in certain places inside of my HTML file. Now I would like to modify the CSS of this tag so inside my CSS file I went:

```css
scroll-content{
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

It did what it was supposed to, but is this the proper way of styling the custom tags?

I can't add a class to them because I do not create the tags, the framework does, so I can't access them in my code and I would like to avoid using Javascript to find these tags and adding classes that way.

I would prefer to know the standard/safest way of modifying custom tags.

Comment: Yes, that is perfectly fine. `scroll-content{}` is selecting a tag.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can apply CSS to custom elements just like you can to standard HTML elements.

There's nothing wrong with `scroll-content { ... }`, as written in your code.

---

*A Little Background*

The browser, at a basic level, has no clue what elements exist. It doesn't recognize anything... ***until*** it is exposed to the default style sheet ([sample](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/sample.html)).

The default style sheet introduces the browser to HTML elements.

Custom elements can therefore be defined as elements that are not included in the default style sheet. (Elements that exist, but are unsupported by the browser, could share this definition.)

Custom elements could, however, be introduced to the browser in author styles.

*Here's something important to consider:*

If the browser doesn't recognize an element (i.e., it's not in the default style sheet), it will apply CSS *initial values*.

> [**6.1.1 Specified
>   values**](https://drafts.csswg.org/css2/cascade.html#specified-value)
>
> User agents must first assign a specified value to each property based
>   on the following mechanisms (in order of precedence):
>
> 1. If the cascade results in a value, use it.
> 2. Otherwise, if the property is inherited and the element is not the root of the document tree, use the computed value of the parent
>      element.
> 3. Otherwise use the property's initial value. The initial value of each property is indicated in the property's definition.

As outlined above, if an element is unrecognized (#1 & #2 don't apply), use the initial value from the property definition (#3 applies).

So in your case:

- Your custom element is: `<scroll-content>`
- Your CSS is: `scroll-content { overflow: hidden; }`
- You say in your question that this code does what it's supposed to do. But unless the framework you mention provides additional styles for custom elements, it cannot work ([demo](https://jsfiddle.net/nrd16dyg/)).

Here's why:

- Since `<scroll-element>` is not in the default style sheet it will use CSS initial values.
- Well, [the initial value of the `display` property is `inline`](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visuren.html#display-prop).
- But [the `overflow` property only works on block elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visufx.html#overflow).

So there's no way this HTML/CSS combination could work – the `overflow` property would be ignored, as would `height`, `width` and any other properties that don't apply to inline elements.

A custom element would need to have `display: block` applied for `overflow` to work ([demo](https://jsfiddle.net/nrd16dyg/2/)).

Similarly, the only reason `body`, `div`, `h1`, `p`, `ul` exist as block elements is because they are defined this way in the default style sheet ([sample](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/sample.html)).

So, putting aside the arguments for and against custom elements, here's the bottom line:

*Add `display: block` to your custom elements and you're good-to-go.*

Comment: Great reply, thank you. Have you managed to test this on the older IE 7,8,9 browsers?

Answer (score -1):

It would be preferable if you can avoid using custom tags since you never know when those tags may become standardized or have a specific usage at some point.

I think it would be safer if you create a class to that custom tag, something like:

```
.scroll-content{
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

This should do it.

Comment: I believe dasherized tags will never become part of the standard in the future. In any case, the OP already said he cannot add classes.

Comment: True, I didn't pay attention to his class comment, my bad. In that case I would style the custom tag the way he did it. This might help too: https://www.w3.org/TR/custom-elements/

Comment: @Mehdi Based on your comment `you did not pay attention...`  your answer is more like a comment `would not recommend to use custom tags`.

Answer (score -1):

Cannot exist standard tags with a hyphen "-" in his name, so there is not such problem.