# Why is this unordered list rendering inline?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have the following HTML code with some internal CSS:

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333333;
}
li {
  float: left;
}
li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
li a:hover {
  background-color: #111111;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

The above code displays a horizontal menu.

As per my knowledge, unless we use `display: inline` property we can't display a list horizontally. Then how could it happen in above code where `display: inline` property has not been used and still the list is displayed horizontally?

Someone please explain me.

Thanks.

Comment: Who told you «unless we use "display:inline" property we can't display a list horizontally» ? That's false, and your example proves it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> As per my knowledge, unless we use `display: inline` property, we can't display a list horizontally. Then how could it happen in above code where `display: inline` property has not been used and still the list is displayed horizontally?

Actually, there are several ways to display elements on the same row. Here are just a few:

- `display: inline`
- `display: inline-block`
- `display: flex` (on the parent)
- create a custom element with no `display` specified

and, like in your code:

- `float: left`

*From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float):*

> The `float` CSS property specifies that an element should be taken
>   from the normal flow and placed along the left or right side of its
>   container, where text and inline elements will wrap around it.

Also, [the initial value of the `display` property is `inline`](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visuren.html#display-prop).

This means that *all* elements are `display: inline`, by default. (Hence, why custom elements appear on the list above.)

It isn't until a browser parses its [*default style sheet*](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/sample.html) that some elements become `display: block` and render on separate lines.

Here's a more in-depth explanation: [Proper way to apply CSS to HTML5 custom elements](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36380449/3597276)

Comment: And also CSS tables, CSS grids, blocks in vertical writing-mode, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `float: left` from the css, becaue it also inline the list. see below

```
li {
  float: left;
}
```