# Removing padding/margin consistently in multiple wraps

Tags: html, css

I’m trying to get the light green to be disappeared (not gone but underneath the dark green).

It’s the exact same problem as my previous post ([Remove padding/margin between elements in shrink-to-fit container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41472306/remove-padding-margin-between-elements-in-shrink-to-fit-container)) but the only thing that’s different is the wrap is inside another wrap, and none of the zero margins/paddings, display inline-blocks or overflows work.

```css
#footer-left{
 float:left;
 width:700px;
 height:200px;
 background:#CC3;
}
#footer-services-contents-wrap{
 background:#030;
 width:auto;
 height:auto;
 display:inline-block;
}
#footer-services-title-wrap{
 background:#0F0;
 width:auto;
 height:auto;
 display:inline-block;
}
.footer-wrap-left{
 width:auto;
 height:auto;
 display: inline-block;
 border-left:1px solid #ccc;
 padding-left:50px;
 padding:0;
 border:none;
 float:left;
}
ul.footer {
    list-style-type:none;
    padding: 0px;
 color:#666;
 font-weight:100;
 font-family:verdana,arial,"Times New Roman", Times, serif,georgia,serif,helvetica;
 font-size:20px;
 margin: 10px 0 0 0;
}

.footer-wrap-right{
 width:auto;
 height:auto;
 display: inline-block;
 border-left:1px solid #ccc;
 padding-left:50px;
 padding:0 0 0 50px;
 border:none;
 float:left;
}
```

```html
<div id="footer-left">

<div id="footer-services-title-wrap">
<div id="footer-services-contents-wrap">

<div class="footer-wrap-left">
<f1>text goes here</f1>
<ul class="footer">
  <li>text text</li>
  <li>text text</li>
  <li>text text</li>
</ul>
</div>

<div class="footer-wrap-right">
<f1>more text goes here</f1>
<ul class="footer">
  <li>text text</li>
  <li>text text</li>
  <li>text text</li>
</ul>
</div>

</div>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: if you want the light green to be behind the olive (dark green?) then why not just have the footer-services-title-wrap to be before the footer-left?

Comment: because I'm going to have other content going into footer-left

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `float:left` when using `inline-block` in your `footer-wrap-right` and `footer-wrap-left` classes:

```css
#footer-left{
 float:left;
 width:700px;
 height:200px;
 background:#CC3;
}
#footer-services-contents-wrap{
 background:#030;
 width:auto;
 height:auto;
 display:inline-block;
}
#footer-services-title-wrap{
 background:#0F0;
 width:auto;
 height:auto;
 display:inline-block;
}
.footer-wrap-left{
 width:auto;
 height:auto;
 display: inline-block;
 border-left:1px solid #ccc;
 padding-left:50px;
 padding:0;
 border:none;
}
ul.footer {
    list-style-type:none;
    padding: 0px;
 color:#666;
 font-weight:100;
 font-family:verdana,arial,"Times New Roman", Times, serif,georgia,serif,helvetica;
 font-size:20px;
 margin: 10px 0 0 0;
}

.footer-wrap-right{
 width:auto;
 height:auto;
 display: inline-block;
 border-left:1px solid #ccc;
 padding-left:50px;
 padding:0 0 0 50px;
 border:none;
}
```

```html
<div id="footer-left">

<div id="footer-services-title-wrap">
<div id="footer-services-contents-wrap">

<div class="footer-wrap-left">
<f1>text goes here</f1>
<ul class="footer">
  <li>text text</li>
  <li>text text</li>
  <li>text text</li>
</ul>
</div>

<div class="footer-wrap-right">
<f1>more text goes here</f1>
<ul class="footer">
  <li>text text</li>
  <li>text text</li>
  <li>text text</li>
</ul>
</div>

</div>
</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem can be solved by adding `float:left` to `#footer-services-contents-wrap`

Reason why it happen:

> Block formatting contexts are important for the positioning (see
>   float) and clearing (see clear) of floats. The rules for positioning
>   and clearing of floats apply only to things within the same block
>   formatting context. Floats do not affect the layout of things in other
>   block formatting contexts, and clear only clears past floats in the
>   same block formatting context.

https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#block-formatting

```css
#footer-left{
 float:left;
 width:700px;
 height:200px;
 background:#CC3;
}
#footer-services-contents-wrap{
 background:#030;
 width:auto;
 height:auto;
 display:inline-block;
        float: left;
}
#footer-services-title-wrap{
 background:#0F0;
 width:auto;
 height:auto;
 display:inline-block;
}
.footer-wrap-left{
 width:auto;
 height:auto;
 display: inline-block;
 border-left:1px solid #ccc;
 padding-left:50px;
 padding:0;
 border:none;
 float:left;
}
ul.footer {
    list-style-type:none;
    padding: 0px;
 color:#666;
 font-weight:100;
 font-family:verdana,arial,"Times New Roman", Times, serif,georgia,serif,helvetica;
 font-size:20px;
 margin: 10px 0 0 0;
}

.footer-wrap-right{
 width:auto;
 height:auto;
 display: inline-block;
 border-left:1px solid #ccc;
 padding-left:50px;
 padding:0 0 0 50px;
 border:none;
 float:left;
}
```

```html
<div id="footer-left">

<div id="footer-services-title-wrap">
<div id="footer-services-contents-wrap">

<div class="footer-wrap-left">
<f1>text goes here</f1>
<ul class="footer">
  <li>text text</li>
  <li>text text</li>
  <li>text text</li>
</ul>
</div>

<div class="footer-wrap-right">
<f1>more text goes here</f1>
<ul class="footer">
  <li>text text</li>
  <li>text text</li>
  <li>text text</li>
</ul>
</div>

</div>
</div>

</div>
```