# Is there a <div> or <span> equivalent for having by default the CSS property display: flex;?

Tags: html

Is there a `<div>` or `<span>` equivalent for having by default the CSS property `display: flex` ?

Comment: No, but you can find a soluton here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9845011/are-custom-elements-valid-html5 ... which answers might be a possible duplicate to this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No such thing exists at the moment :(

But...

You could make your own in some browsers...

HTML:

```
<flex>
    <div>Foo</div>
    <div>Bar</div>
</flex>
```

CSS:

```
flex {
    display: flex;
}
```

Comment: you need to use a hyphen for custom Tags

Comment: No you don't, not in plain HTML5/CSS

Comment: Forgive my possible lack of understanding, but that seems to be for creating custom elements with special functionality. All we're doing here is dropping some CSS on an arbitrary block.

Answer (score 1):

None. Tried checking if there is a flex tag using HTML5... :(