# a "preprocessor" for HTML? without JS

Tags: html, css, custom-element

In a CSS sheet, I created a new tag

```
gb {
    color: green;
}
```

and in the HTML code, I would replace **without javascript**, all occurences of

```
<gb> &#9632; </gb>  <!-- green bullet -->
```

with something like `<gb />` . *(Like using the C preprocessor, but doing thing in native HTML/CSS, without need to another program (cpp) and action (preprocessing) before sending the page on the web)*

In other terms, how could I create custom HTML tag, with content (saving typing the `&#9632;` code), but only using HTML/CSS ?

And, yes, a lot of content already address custom HTML tags, but

1. They generally use Javascript
2. It is not clear
3. I can't believe such a little thing could involve these cumbersome solutions.

**The idea is just to have *a short way* to draw an Unicode symbol (and in color) *in middle of text*.**

Comment: It does not really matter whether you “can believe it” or not ... that doesn’t change the basic fact that this is not possible in any trivial way using HTML & CSS alone.

Comment: HTML does not allow you to create custom elements (there is a custom element spec, but it is still a draft and your code doesn't conform to it)

Comment: This is probably something best achieved with a `<li>` and some styling of the natural bullet.

Comment: Basically you can write `<gb>` tag to HTML and it will act as normal `<div>`.

Comment: @Justinas — It won't. Error recovery will treat it more like a `<span>`. It's still best avoided.

Comment: You can do something like this - https://jsfiddle.net/3mabnomt/ but your markup is not valid. It's not recommended to create custom tags like that

Comment: @CBroe What with the answer below...?

Comment: @Quentin Maybe, but the goal is to put this tag alone, in many locations in the document.

Comment: @yO_ what about it? That is CSS generated content, yes. But that has absolutely nothing to do with custom elements of any sort.

Comment: @CBroe Because we define a new `<gb>` tag, that is not in native HTML?..

Comment: Why you should not be doing that in the first place (especially if you don’t want to use any JavaScript), Quentin has already pointed out in comments. CSS generated content is a “feature” of CSS, yes. But is has no connection whatsoever with custom elements. This would work the same way if you applied it to a `div` for example.

Comment: Why this question and answer are being downvoted? OP asked for a way to not duplicate symbols inside custom tags. Answer has been added. It's working and fits question. What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Option 1

You can (*but you should not*) create your own HTML tag:

```css
gb::before {
  content: "\25A0";
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<gb>Your text</gb>
```

### Option 2

You can use a list with `<ul>` an `<li>` tags:

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0px;
}

li:before {
  content: "\25A0";
  color: green;
  padding-right:5px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Line 1</li>
  <li>Line 2</li>
  <li>Line 3</li>
</ul>
```

### Option 3

You can use a `<span>` tag :

```css
.gb::before {
  content: "\25A0";
  color: green;
  padding-right:5px;
}
```

```html
<span class="gb">Your text</span>
```

Comment: That HTML is wrong. Aside from being invalid, error recovery doesn't handle void elements. It will be treated as a start tag, not a complete element.

Comment: Good! It almost worked! Not with just `<gb/>` (putted all the text after in green), but with `<gb></gb>`.

Comment: @Quentin Don't agree with you. It's valid to create custom HTML tags. Here is [related question about this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9845011/are-custom-elements-valid-html5).

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov — The Custom Elements Specification is (a) a draft and (b) doesn't allow `gb` as a tag name for a custom element. So no, it isn't valid. Also (c) you haven't written the JavaScript (which the OP said they didn't want to use) to register the custom element. [They are also not widely supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=custom-elements).

Comment: @Quentin OK, you are right. I've seen a lot of custom tags and thought it was valid HTML.

Comment: @Vadim Ovchinnikov  My second proposition allows us to do the same thing properly. What is your opinion on this new solution?

Comment: @ValentinGenevrais The question was not for a list... More to put this square symbol in many places...

Comment: Ok, you can use my first proposition if you think it's the best for you

Comment: @ValentinGenevrais To be honest I was OK even with first solution. I didn't care about HTML validity. This works in all browsers, why should anybody care?

Comment: HTML validity is important when you work with a team on the same file.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov — Forwards compatibility with future extensions to HTML. To allow people who have to maintain your code to understand it.

Comment: @Quentin Well, I don't use custom tags, but I think it's the matter of preference. Regarding maintainability, I don't agree with this statement. Structure like `<div class="awesome-block"></div>` looks nearly the same for me as `<awesome-block></awesome-block>`. Regarding the future, it's also quite possible that custom tags will be perfectly legal in HTML.

Comment: @yO_ Please, use the third option. It is important to have good practices.

Comment: @ValentinGenevrais Thank you! But it is long to insert `<span class="gb"></span>` in many places and in the middle of a text... The idea is just, to have a short way to draw an Unicode symbol (and in color) in middle of text...

Comment: @Quentin Also the question was not about if it's good practice or not. Angular 2 uses custom tags in their examples and they work everywhere. BTW if HTML will drastically change we'll have to rewrite our code but I'm sure we will have new `DOCTYPE`s and old code will work as expected. I'm sure that guys who will develop new spec will also think about that custom tags were used and find a way to solve this problem.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9845011/are-custom-elements-valid-html5?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @Quentin
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9845011/are-custom-elements-valid-html5?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @ValentinGenevrais — I've already made comments about that specification. I'm not inclined to repeat myself.

Answer (score 1):

To use a [custom tag](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/custom-elements.html#custom-elements) that is valid regarding the HTML Living Standard, you'll just need to use a hyphen in your tag name.

```
<g-b>Hello</g-b>
```

Then you can follow the Valentin's answer "Option 1".

```css
g-b::before {
  content: "\25A0";
  color: green;
}

r-b::before {
  content: "\25A0";
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<g-b>Text 1</g-b>
<br>
<r-b></r-b>Text 2
```