# DTD for a custom meta tag

Tags: html, meta-tags, dtd

I am creating a meta tag like

```
<META name="importantElement" elementID=... />
```

Is there a way in the .dtd to mark that `<META name="importantElement"` also requires the `elementID` attribute?

Comment: Does HTML5 even use a DTD?

Comment: @j08691: No. (I'm guessing you mentioned HTML5 because this is neither valid HTML nor XHTML syntax, regardless of any DTD customizations...)

Comment: If no DTD, is there a mechanism / what is the mechanism by which I can validate the custom tags I've created?

Comment: AFAIK they will validate only with an XHTML doctype. But I'm not sure you can put a rule like "attribute elementID is required if name is 'importantElement', else implied" in a DTD. Attributes don't influence each other.

Comment: The only way I found to make this work (that is, validate; it doesn't do anything else) is to add `elementid` to the ATTLIST of `meta` in the doctype declaration. But like I said, it then is always optional; it can't be made dependent on other attributes. And if you want to leave the `content` attribute out of such a `meta` command, then you'll have no choice but to make that attribute optional as well. Here is an example XHTML file I made: http://temp.strictquirks.nl/test-new-attribute.xhtml But I'd be delighted if someone would come up with an actual solution.

Comment: @MrLister I wonder that myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the very helpful comments posted on this question, the answer is that you can't enforce a dependency between attributes using a dtd, that HTML 5 does not use a .dtd, and HTML 5 support for custom tags is handled in a subset(?) of web browsers through Web Components, as per the post I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9845011/are-custom-elements-valid-html5)