# Can I name elements within components anything I want?

Tags: reactjs

If I have lets say App component, like this

```
    const App = () => {
         return(
            <div>
                <p>hello world</p>
             </div>)}
```

can I name div whatever i want like I did below? It works in the browser just fine but Im not sure,

```
      const App = () => {
           return(
                <whatever>
                     <p>hello world</p>
                </whatever>)}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are custom elements valid HTML5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9845011/are-custom-elements-valid-html5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes You can. But:

1. if You want to work with React, don't capitalize the name of div like this: `<Whatever>`, because it will seems to React that this is an another Component.
2. And when Your project gets bigger, it will start to get more complicated, so its a good practice to write tags by they names.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can name them whatever you like, people often do it so the markup is a bit more friendly to read and understand. For example [Appcues](https://www.appcues.com/) injects their widget into your website and if you look at the markup for it, it has elements like `<appcues/>`.

Just check the browser support for these custom HTML tags, I think most major ones do support it but just to be safe.