# Why I get an error in Vue when using custom HTML tags?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, vue.js, tags

I really enjoy Vue I'm a newbie trying to use just a custom tag:

`<ui-button>Learn more</ui-button>`

However I get an error saying that I have to register that component. So, to solve this I used: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#ignoredElements

I tried in other frameworks too and not errors are shown but other frameworks follow different approach. Maybe is not possible to distinguish between a component and a custom tag.

> custom component = custom tag + encapsulated behavior and style

Is possible to avoid this in Vue without registering my tags as components?

**Update**

Thank you so much for your time and efforts and please I'm not saying other frameworks are better. I just wanna avoid over-engineering and use simple custom tags to make the HTML document more readable.

Comment: Could you provide a complete example of your code? in Vue you have to register your component importing in parent component and passing in components property or globally.

Comment: @David thank you so much, you can add that line of code anywhere in your template in Vue to see the error. It's not a real component, I'm just using standard HTML tags. If you do the same in React in your JSX there isn't errors in the console.

Comment: `<ui-button>` is [not an HTML component](https://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/default.ASP) that your browser understands. That's how Vue references a component (not a custom tag). Vue's compiler is telling you that you placed a component on the screen but didn't tell Vue how to find it. React and Vue are not the same thing and shouldn't be expected to act the same way.

Comment: yes Bryce it's a custom tag, we can use it and it makes the HTML document more readable! I'm not saying that other frameworks are better. I don't care I'm just wanna avoid over-engineering. I understand that React and Vue are not the same thing and don't have to act the same way : ) I have updated my question. Thank you so much for your well documented answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should register components globally or locally.

**Global registration**

```
Vue.component('my-component-name', {
  // ... options ...
})
```

**Local registration (in another component)**

```
import ComponentA from './ComponentA.vue'

export default {
  components: {
    ComponentA
  },
  // ...
}
```

More information about that https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html

Comment: Thank you so much Emïls, but it's not a component I'm just using standard HTML tags. So, you mean is not possible? Why I need to add that in Vue and not in React?

Comment: There isn't standard html tag `<ui-button>`

Comment: Sorry, you are right, I didn't explain myself I mean it's valid html tag, a custom element without encapsulation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9845011/are-custom-elements-valid-html5#:~:text=The%20name%20of%20a%20custom,custom%20elements%20from%20regular%20elements.

Comment: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/customelements/

Comment: https://coryrylan.com/blog/using-web-components-in-vue try to install and import web-component-essentials