# Would making up an HTML tag break anything?

Tags: html

I'm currently working on a piece of interactive fiction, and part of it requires the reader to look at the HTML document itself. I want to make it as readable as possible, especially for people who aren't used to looking at HTML documents. I already am using very specific class names to style certain elements (i.e. `<span class="game_mechanic_A">`) but there are parts of the text that I want to "highlight"/draw attention to in a more streamlined manner.

I was thinking I could do `This text is <foo>important</foo> for the story` instead of `This text is <span class="foo">important</span> for the story`. In my own testing it seems to work fine, but I am absolutely not an expert on HTML so I don't know if there's something I'm missing. I have noticed that in the inspect pane/panel it formats it like so:

```
This text is
<foo>important</foo>
for the story
```

...which feels like a nice bonus, since it brings even more attention to what's in `<foo>`. Would I be making a huge mistake if I do this? I don't actually want the tag to *do* anything, just be "formatting" in the HTML document.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are custom elements valid HTML5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9845011/are-custom-elements-valid-html5)

Comment: It would do nothing to your eyes, but screen readers would be awfully confused!

Answer (score 0):

**Mostly, no.**
What's the difference between the two snippets below?

```html
<invalidtag>some tag</invalidtag>
```

```html
<span>some tag</span>
```

You can't see any difference in the rendering output. But this doesn't mean it is always no.

**The browser renders it as an inline element, like <span>. So, if you replace <span> with <invalidtag>, it will still work.**

**This is really bad practice though, don't do it!**

- It triggers a markup validation error: `Unknown tag <invalidtag>`.
- Screen readers do not know how to handle it. The blind people are cut off from enjoying your site.

So, invalid tags are rendered as spans, **but don't do it.**

To make it more clear:

```html
<p>This is a p tag with a <span style="color:red;">red span</span> inside.</p>

<p>This is a p tag with a <invalidtag style="color:red;">red invalid tag</invalidtag> inside.</p>

<small><em>No difference, eh? Try using a screen reader or looking below!</em></small>

<p>This is a <div style="background-color:cyan; border:1px solid black;">div</div> inside a p tag.</p>

<p>This is a <badtag style="background-color:cyan; border:1px solid black;">bad tag</badtag> inside a p tag.</p>
```