# Random Letter html Tag

Tags: html, tags

I was wondering if you can use a random letter as an html tag. Like, f isn't a tag, but I tried it in some code and it worked just like a span tag. Sorry if this is a bad question, I've just been curious about it for a while, and I couldn't find anything online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I was wondering if you can use a random letter as an html tag.

Yes and no.

"Yes" - in that *it works*, but it isn't *correct*: when you have something like `<z>` it only works because the web (HTML+CSS+JS) has a degree of *forwards compatibility* built-in: browsers will render HTML elements that they don't recognize basically the same as a `<span>` (i.e. an `inline` element that doesn't do anything other than [reify](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reification_(computer_science)) a range of the document's text).

However, [to use HTML5 Custom Elements *correctly*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9845011/are-custom-elements-valid-html5) you need to conform to the Custom Elements specification which states:

> The name of a custom element must contain a dash (-). So `<x-tags>`, `<my-element>`, and `<my-awesome-app>` are all valid names, while `<tabs>` and `<foo_bar>` are not. This requirement is so the HTML parser can distinguish custom elements from regular elements. It also ensures forward compatibility when new tags are added to HTML.

So if you use `<my-z>` then you'll be fine.

---

[The HTML *Living Standard* document, as of 2021-12-04](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#valid-custom-element-name), indeed makes an explicit reference to forward-compatibility in its list of requirements for custom element names:

> https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#valid-custom-element-name
>
> - They start with an ASCII lower alpha, ensuring that the HTML parser will treat them as tags instead of as text.
> - They do not contain any ASCII upper alphas, ensuring that the user agent can always treat HTML elements ASCII-case-insensitively.
> - They contain a hyphen, used for namespacing and to ensure forward compatibility (since no elements will be added to HTML, SVG, or MathML with hyphen-containing local names in the future).
> - They can always be created with `createElement()` and `createElementNS()`, which have restrictions that go beyond the parser's.
> - Apart from these restrictions, a large variety of names is allowed, to give maximum flexibility for use cases like `<math-α>` or `<emotion->`.

---

So, by example:

- `<a>`, `<q>`, `<b>`, `<i>`, `<u>`, `<p>`, `<s>`

  - **No**: these single-letter elements are already used by HTML.
- `<z>`

  - **No**: element names that don't contain a hyphen `-` cannot be custom elements and will be interpreted by present-day browsers as invalid/unrecognized markup that they will nevertheless (largely) treat  the same as a `<span>` element.
- `<a:z>`

  - **No**: using a colon to use an XML element namespace is *not a thing* in HTML5 unless you're using XHTML5.
- `<-z>`

  - **No** - the element name must start with a lowercase ASCII character from `a` to `z`, so `-` is not allowed.
- `<a-z>`

  - **Yes** - this is fine.
- `<a->` and `<a-->`

  - **Unsure** - these two names are curious:

    - The HTML spec says the name must match the grammar rule `[a-z] (PCENChar)* '-' (PCENChar)*`.

      - The `*` denotes "zero-or-more" which is odd, because that implies the hyphen doesn't *need* to be followed by another character.
      - `PCENChar` represents a huge range of visible characters permitted in element names, curiously this includes `-`, so by that rule `<a-->` *should* be valid.

        - But note that `--` is a reserved character sequence in the greater SGML-family (including HTML and XML) which may cause weirdness. YMMV!