# Are Blazor Components like going back to Web Form Controls?

Tags: html, blazor

I have worked mostly with ASP.NET Web Forms in the past and am currently in the process of learning Razor Pages and Blazor. I know about Web Forms' shortcomings, one of them being that on the source view you don't see valid HTML markup with all the proprietary Web Form Control tags junk, not to mention the horrible HTML markup that got rendered and you had no way to fix because you had no control.

When I started reading up on Razor Pages, from what I read this was one of the advantages, that it's all valid HTML on the source view and you can (mostly) copy/paste it unprocessed and it would render fine in a browser, if you ever needed to. It was a welcome change, as I consider myself a bit of an HTML purist, but really this was more a nice-to-have  rather than a must-have.

But lately I've been getting into Blazor and when I learned about Blazor Components, I was shocked to see that they need to be called with invalid HTML tags. To use MudBlazor as an example, I mean tags like `<MudLayout>` and `<MudDataGrid>`.

Is it just me? And correct me if I'm wrong but, isn't this like going back to Web Forms all over again? I thought this was precisely what we were trying to move away from.

Comment: This is asking for opinions. I don't think any (server-side) framework can be "all valid HTML".  Focus on how intelligible and workable the end result is.

Comment: This is an opinion based question and will probably get closed.  Your looking at Razor markup code which gets compiled into C# classes that output their html through a `RenderTreeBuilder`.  Dig deeper before you jump to hasty conclusions.  Read up about what Razor markup files are and how they get compiled.  For example, this is  `InputText` = https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Components/Web/src/Forms/InputText.cs

Comment: You have plenty of control over the HTML markup. Webforms did not have 'tag junk', it has server tags for C# equivalents to HTML entities so that you can take advantage of server-side functionality from a client-side environment. All that 'tag junk' gets converted to valid HTML on compile anyway. Usually when I see people complaining about Webforms or its "shortcomings", it's actually a lack of understanding about the point of Webforms. This case appears to be no different. Would that modern ASP.NET Core workflows enjoyed even a fraction of the simplicity of Webforms development... *sigh*

Comment: Also, it seems that perhaps you have not heard of [Custom HTML elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9845011/are-custom-elements-valid-html5)