# HTMLSpanElement vs. HTMLUnknownElement

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, browser

References:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSpanElement
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLUnknownElement

Is there any real difference between these?

i.e. Have any scenarios been found (IE8+) where these two elements (spann and span) behave differently?

```
<body>
    <spann></spann> <!-- where this could be any unknown element -->
    <span></span>
</body>
```

where the preceding dom structure is created via the following JavaScript:

```
var body = document.body;
var spann = document.createElement("spann");
var span = document.createElement("span");

body.appendChild(spann);
body.appendChild(span);
```

Comment: They do behave different in IE8 as in IE8 the `divv` is treated as an inline element and the `div` as a block element

Comment: Yes, if you Google, you'll find there are various issues with custom elements in IE8.

Comment: @LGSon I've updated the question to reflect span instead of div

Comment: @squint Also updated the question so that the DOM is constructed with js instead of being static html.

Answer (score 5):

According to both the [HTML 5 spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#the-span-element) and the [HTML 4.0.1 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#edef-SPAN), the only conveyed meaning by `span` is `display:inline;`- which [is the default behavior](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) of all elements before ***which*** element is considered.

The only difference that SHOULD exist between an `HTMLSpanElement` and an `HTMLUnknownElement` is that the former is tied to a `span` and the latter is not.

Note that only [Global Attributes and Events](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110405/elements.html#global-attributes) will have built-in interfaces from `HTMLUnknownElement`, and that `span` also only has the global attributes/events defined for it (see the spec links at the top).

---

What this means depends on what you want to do.

If you're wanting to go from `cstm-elem` to `span`, you are likely safe, as the spec pretty clearly states that `span` is just a generic `inline` (with `div` being a generic `block`).

If you're wanting to go from `span` to `cstm-elem`, IE8 has historically been terrible for that, and [replacing the latter with the former](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6854813/5116879) is the general solution suggested to this problem.

Good news, though, IE 8 has been EOL since mid January, 2016. Was quite a party we threw, shame you couldn't be there.